# No SELECT DISTINCT exists but I get: The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql-server

So I have a query that does not have a `SELECT DISTINCT` in it, but I am getting a `The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable` error. This same query has been running for years without error and all of a sudden it's not working. I most like changed the data type of a column to text in one of the tables, but still... there is no `DISTINCT` in the query, so why the error.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
            s.dept_abrev + ' ' + s.crs_num + ' ' + s.section_code AS course,
            app.approval_id,
            app.role_id,
            r.role_name,
            app.section_id,
            d.delivery_method,
            app.approve,
            app.reject,
            app.notes,
            x.xl_code,
            x.xl_cap,
            s.section_cap,
            rt.role_priority,
            p.person_id,
            p.f_name + ' ' + p.l_name AS approver_name,
            p.email,
            ip.person_id AS inst_person_id, 
            ip.f_name + ' ' + ip.l_name AS instructor_name,
            'RCDE' AS who
        FROM
            cas_Approval app
            INNER JOIN cas_Sections s ON (s.section_id = app.section_id) 
                AND s.section_status_id IN (3,4)
            INNER JOIN cas_Contract AS c ON (c.section_id = app.section_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_Instructor AS i ON (i.instructor_id = c.instructor_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_Person AS ip ON (i.person_id = ip.person_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_Role r ON (app.role_id = r.role_id)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN cas_XLCode x ON (x.xl_id = s.xl_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_DeliveryMethod d ON (d.delivery_id = s.delivery_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_RoleTypes rt ON (rt.role_type_id = r.role_type_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_PersonToRole AS ptr ON r.role_id = ptr.role_id 
            INNER JOIN cas_Person AS p ON ptr.person_id = p.person_id
            INNER JOIN cas_semesters sem ON s.semester_id = sem.semester_id
                AND sem.is_template = 0
        WHERE
            app.approve IS NULL
            AND (SELECT COUNT(reject) FROM cas_Approval WHERE section_id = s.section_id OR section_id = s.parent_section_id) = 0
            AND app.reject IS NULL 
            AND s.semester_id = 27
            AND ip.person_id <> p.person_id

        UNION
        SELECT
            c.dept_abrev + ' ' + c.crs_num + ' ' + c.sectionCode AS course,
            app.approval_id,
            app.role_id,
            r.role_name,
            app.section_id,
            (CASE c.instructMethod 
                WHEN 'P' THEN 'Traditional'
                WHEN 'I' THEN 'Online'
                WHEN 'R' THEN 'Broadcast'
            END) AS delivery_method,
            app.approve,
            app.reject,
            app.notes,
            c.xlCode AS xl_code,
            NULL AS xl_cap,
            c.courseCap AS section_cap,
            rt.role_priority,
            p.person_id,
            p.f_name + ' ' + p.l_name AS approver_name,
            p.email,
            ip.person_id AS inst_person_id,
            insFirstName + ' ' + insLastName AS instructor_name,
            'USU-E' AS who
        FROM
            cas_Approval app
            INNER JOIN cas_usuECourses c ON (c.id = app.eastId) 
                AND c.status IN ('P','A','S')
            INNER JOIN cas_Role r ON (app.role_id = r.role_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_RoleTypes rt ON (rt.role_type_id = r.role_type_id)
            INNER JOIN cas_PersonToRole AS ptr ON r.role_id = ptr.role_id 
            INNER JOIN cas_Person p ON ptr.person_id = p.person_id
            INNER JOIN cas_semesters sem ON c.termCode = sem.banner_term_code
                AND sem.is_template = 0
            LEFT OUTER JOIN cas_person ip ON c.insAnumber = ip.a_num
        WHERE
            app.approve IS NULL
            AND (SELECT COUNT(reject) FROM cas_Approval WHERE eastId = c.id) = 0
            AND app.reject IS NULL 
            AND sem.semester_id = 27
        ORDER BY
            p.person_id,
            app.role_id,
            course
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UNION clause causes a DISTINCT.

Blog post describing your exact problem:
[SQL unions and the text data type](http://progblog10.blogspot.com/2010/11/sql-unions-and-text-data-type.html)

Comment: I didn't know that and figured something was forcing a DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

TEXT can't be used with `DISTINCT` (and several other functions). In any event, `TEXT` is [to be deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) and should be replaced by a type such as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, which does allow distinct.

```
CREATE Table SomeTable
(
  TextCol TEXT,
  VarCharMaxCol VARCHAR(MAX)
);
GO

--Err: The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
SELECT DISTINCT TextCol FROM SomeTable;
-- Works
SELECT DISTINCT VarCharMaxCol FROM SomeTable;
```

Comment: I've since see that, but doesn't VARCHAR(MAX) have a smaller cap than text? Or not one I would realistically hit? This field is a free form text entry and sometimes people try to paste in email threads rather than use the field as designed.

Comment: Both [TEXT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) and [VARCHAR(MAX)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) have a 2GB limit. AFAIK there are no downsides to `VARCHAR(MAX)` over TEXT - it is a step forward.

Answer (score 1):

Text fields were designed for data that doesn't get compared or sorted.  For example, a library would never place 'Fahrenheit 451' next to 'The Bell Jar' because one begins "It was a p..." and the other begins "It was a q...".

The quick fix to your problem: use `UNION ALL`.  The long-term fix is to not use `text`

`SELECT CAST('' AS text) UNION SELECT CAST('' AS text)` <-- error

`SELECT CAST('' AS text) UNION ALL SELECT CAST('' AS text)` <-- no error